# Are downvotes zero cost?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I've just gotten a downvote on an answer in main and it did not result in a decrease in my total rep. Is this normal?

Comment: There was a special sale today: upvote twice, get a free downvote!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is normal in the sense that I converted the question to community wiki before the downvoter downvoted.

Comment: Ah! I did not notice that it'd been CWed. Thanks.